# UITextField in a TableViewCell doesn't appear

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I want to make a TableView Cell with a Label and Textfield in it, but the Textfield doesn't appear.

Here is the init of the textfield, it's in a cell-class:

```
self.tfTitle = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 70, 100, 20)];
self.tfTitle.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
self.tfTitle.placeholder = @"Titel/Ort";
self.tfTitle.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
self.tfTitle.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
[self addSubview:self.tfTitle];
```

Comment: How big is your cell?  Give it's frame dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `[self.contentView addSubview:self.tfTitle];`

Also change your frame `CGRectMake(20, 70, 100, 20)` to `CGRectMake(20, 10, 100, 20)`

70 is too far from the top so that you cannot see it.

Answer (score 2):

Since iOS7, `UITableViewCell` hierarchy has changed, consider adding the `UITextField` to `self.contentView`

```
[self.contentView addSubview:self.tfTitle];
```

It might not be the problem, but still, if you make it appear on self, you won't be able to select the textfield.

ALso make sure the frame you give it is in the cell (*put some background color to the contentView of the self and to your textfield*)